# How to load Flat files to SQL Server Tables according to the Name of Flat File?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, flatfilesource

There are hundreds of flat files

- for each file i need to create a table in SQL-server and enter the file contents into the table

  ```
  example :
  Flat_Files:             SQL-SERVER Table:
  FileA.txt               fileA
  FileB.txt               fileB
  FileC.txt               fileC  
  ... and so on.
  ```

how to achieve this in SSIS.

Ps: i am beginner to all of this.

Comment: What have you tried so far, and where did you start to get stuck?

Comment: ForEach Item Enumerator, some examples: 

- http://www.sqlerudition.com/example-of-ssis-foreach-loop-item-enumerator-and-dynamic-oledb-connection/ and another one 

- https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/803195/Foreach-File-Enumerator-in-SSIS

Comment: @Larnu i tried using ForEachLoop container

Comment: Could you show us what you tried? What were the problem you had? Why didn't it work?

Comment: Also, i ***assume*** that these tables already exist on your SQL Server, correct? you just need the ETL process to get from the file to the table.

Comment: @Larnu No they are not. I tried with few files as source files but i couldn't figure out how to send each file  to a new table. i.e, create a new table according to file name

Comment: That's a problem. How do you propose that SSIS "works out" what datatype all of your columns are? CSV files are text files, they don't have datatypes, however, that doesn't mean that your data should all be stored as text. This sounds more like you need to design your database first, and then import the data afterwards. SSIS isn't going to help you with the design phase.

Comment: @Larnu I tried also by creating few tables and but couldn't figure out how to send each file's data to corresponding table

Comment: Also, SSIS isn't going to help you if all the files have different definitions. SSIS requires static definitions, so if each file differs in the datatypes/columns it contains you would need to build a different dataflow task, or at least flow within the same task, for every file.

Comment: @Larnu file's data have same datatype(string) no problem in that end. Can i excute this task if database tables are already created according to file names.

Comment: So every table has the same definition and every file does too?

Comment: @Larnu datatype is same but column name is different for each file & table. so if this is the case can i move multiple files data to respective tables?

Comment: No, if the columns differ they don't have static definitions. You'll need to build a separate flow for each file if you want to use SSIS. Like i said, SSIS does not support dynamic definitions; they must be static.

Comment: @Larnu can you please look at this and tell if this is possible http://www.techbrothersit.com/2016/04/how-to-load-flat-files-to-sql-server.html    thank you in advance

Comment: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2874/loop-through-flat-files-in-sql-server-integration-services/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Dynamic SQL in a Script task. 
For each file(use for-each loop container) get the header and file name to create a table and then insert the data into that table using Dynamic SQL.

This should be your last option.

If all the files are .xlsx you can do this using ExecuteSQL Task.

Comment: While this is a good approach to the problem, you'll run into problems defining the data types for each column dynamically.

Comment: I don't think there would be an easy solution to define the column datatypes for 100 files. The only option is to set all the column datatypes to nvarchar.